# Modifying .exe during installation

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I have created a Windows executable for distribution. I've created an installer, using Inno Setup. Everything works, but now in addition I'd like to allow the person installing the software to enter a URL or URI of a configuration file, that my application would use to obtain various initialization data, which will vary by site. Since the application will be used at many locations per site, ideally, the person installing would enter the path to the configuration file once, during installation; then the application would store the configuration file location. Is there a standard way of having an installer add a resource (i.e., the path to the configuration file) to the .exe it's installing? Thanks for any advice.

As an example: each site will have a server that my software will use to obtain information in real-time; the servers will be behind each site's firewall, hence it's a per-site initialization. So, as the software is installed in each workstation at a site, the IT staff would have to provide the URL that my software will use at that site. Each workstation could store that site-specific URL in the registry, as one person had suggested. I was wondering whether there are other possibilities that are better than using the registry (e.g., dynamically creating a string resource in the executable), or whether the registry is the best way forward. I'd like to make installation as painless as possible, so I was thinking an installer that uses a configuration file or command-line to supply the URL would be best.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual ?  Normally it would be saved in the registry.

Comment: I'm familiar with the manual, I'm just trying to determine whether using a string resource or another method (e.g., registry entry, as you suggested) would be best. Thanks!

Comment: If the application is going to be used from multiple locations then clearly the registry is not going to be a good solution. You also don't modify the exe you are installing.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the path to configuration file only once per site, so that the configuration has to be stored on a shared place, accessible from any location on the site? Or once per location is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard way of having an installer add a resource (i.e., the path to the configuration file) to the .exe it's installing?

Yes, there are ways to add or modify resources of an executable, e.g. with [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and similar tools. But i wouldn't call this standard in any way, because it gets complicated, e.g. when your installer executable is signed.
Don't do this - especially not for inserting configuration directives.

In your case, there is an easier, less hack-ish and more maintainable way to achieve the same.

> I have created a Windows executable for distribution. I've created an installer, using Inno Setup.

This means that you can modify and recompile both the application and installer executable.

What i suggest here is to work a bit more on the configuration side of your application:

- modify your application to read a configuration file during bootstrap, e.g. application.ini
- when the configuration file is not there, recreate it with default settings on bootstrap
- add a configuration directive "LocalConfigurationUrl" with an empty value
- add a dialog, which pops up when "LocalConfigurationUrl" is empty, asking for the URL and write it to the config

When you implement it this way your application asks for the path to the configuration URL at the first start.

> ideally, the person installing would enter the path to the configuration file once, during installation; then the application would store the configuration file location

Now, in order to avoid the application asking at startup for configuration, you could modify your Innosetup script to ask for the LocalConfigurationURL during installation and write the application.ini to the application folder. (= application.ini with default configuration + LocalConfigurationUrl with a value.)

You are duplicating the functionality (form asking for url), but your are setting up an application pre-configuration, so that the application runs out-of-the-box with minimal interaction need at the first start.

Comment: It seems that this approach would work with a dialog or command-line parameter to the installer; also, it could write to the registry or to an .ini file. Thanks!